# How to cast SUM return type doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, symfony4

I have a DQL query which return the result of SUM function for the field 'download' as a string.
However, I want to have this field in integer to can sort on it.

Here is my query :

```
public function findBySearchFilterAndPaginationStatistics(OperationFilter $operationFilter = null, array $options = [])
    {
        $orderColumns = [
            'title' => 't.name',
            'idOperation' => 'o.id',
            'name' => 'o.name',
            'editor' => 'oe.name',
            'intermediate' => 'i.name',
            'status' => 'o.status',
            'download' => 'SUM(a.numberOfClicks)',
            'views' => 'SUM(a.numberOfClickers)',
            'date' => 'MAX(a.updatedAt)',
            'parutionsCount' => 'COUNT(DISTINCT a.dateAction)',
            'parutionsAnomaliesCount' => 'COUNT(DISTINCT ano.parution)',
            'anomalies' => 'IF(at.name != \'Aucune anomalies\', COUNT(DISTINCT ano.id), 0)',
        ];

        if (isset($options['columns']) && is_array($options['columns'])) {
            $orderColumns = PaginationUtils::getNewSelectItems($orderColumns, $options['columns']);
        }
        if ($operationFilter === null) {
            return array_keys($orderColumns);
        }

        $orderKey = 'o.id';
        $orderDirection = $options['orderDirection'] ?? 'DESC';

        if (in_array($options['orderKey'], array_keys($orderColumns))) {
            $orderKey = $orderColumns[$options['orderKey']];
        }

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('o');
        $qb->select(PaginationUtils::getColumns($orderColumns));

        $qb->join('o.title', 't')
            ->join('o.createdBy', 'c')
            ->join('t.editor', 'oe')
            ->leftJoin('o.aggregateHits', 'a')
            ->leftJoin('o.anomalie', 'ano', 'WITH', 'ano.status = 1')
            ->leftJoin('ano.anomalieTitle', 'at')
            ->leftJoin('o.rights', 'ri', 'WITH', 'ri.intermediate IS NOT NULL')
            ->leftJoin('ri.intermediate', 'i');

        $qb = $this->commonOperationFilterConditions($qb, $operationFilter);

        if (isset($options['user']) && $options['user'] instanceof User) {
            $qb = $this->commonUserConditions($qb, $options['user'], 'allowToReport');
        }

        unset($orderColumns['download'],
            $orderColumns['views'],
            $orderColumns['date'],
            $orderColumns['parutionsCount'],
            $orderColumns['parutionsAnomaliesCount'],
            $orderColumns['anomalies']);

        $qb->orderBy($orderKey, $orderDirection);

        $qb->groupBy(PaginationUtils::getColumns($orderColumns, 'long'));

        return $qb;
    }
```

Here is the result of one row with download as string :

```
0 => array:12 [
    "title" => "toto"
    "idOperation" => 8601
    "name" => "toto"
    "editor" => "toto"
    "intermediate" => null
    "status" => 0
    "download" => "36324136"
    "views" => "28142082"
    "date" => "2020-09-10 03:30:19"
    "parutionsCount" => "891"
    "parutionsAnomaliesCount" => "2"
    "anomalies" => "2"
  ]
```

How to have 'download' as an integer ?

Symfony's version : 4.4
Doctrine's version : 2

Thank you for your answers.